# Pass a value from PHP app to Angular4 app

Tags: angular

I have integrated an Angular4 app into a WordPress plugin (so in some PHP code). In a view I call all the files I get by making a publish "ng build -prod"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{PLUGIN_URL}}assets/js/inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{PLUGIN_URL}}assets/js/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{PLUGIN_URL}}assets/js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{PLUGIN_URL}}assets/js/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

My Angular app works very well into the PHP code. Now my problem is I need to pass an "id" from the PHP app to the Angular app. What will be the best solution / architecture?

Something like :
    "main.bundle.js?id=".myIdValue."

It would be better that this "id" stay hidden from the final user (so not displayed into the navigator URL...). How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do, is to set a global window variable with php, like

```
echo "<script>window.myIdValue = 'something';</script>";
```

In your angular application you can read this.
Here is a good place, which shows you an example of best practice using global window variable in angular2+ :

https://medium.com/@laco0416/access-to-global-variables-in-angular-2-b2c395eac1d8

Comment: Thanks for your help. The script with "windows" value just have to be called before the other Angular .js in the PHP file and it works!